# Google search preview style jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin which is similar than the new Google search page preview.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search came up with these, I don't have any experience with any of them though..

http://cssglobe.com/post/1695/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/content/thumbnail

Best of luck